# BINARY /etc/hosts file on macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Tags: macos, hosts, macos-mojave

The `/etc/hosts` file on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running 10.14.4 gives me binary when I try to view or edit it. Does anyhow know how this happened or how I can turn it back into ASCII?

See summary and example. I've tried `sudo <arbitrary_editor> /etc/hosts` and `/private/etc/hosts`, but regardless, I see binary, and `file` shows the filetype as `data`.

```
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$ ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2263 Apr 14 16:26 /etc/hosts
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$ cat /etc/hosts
�    r��ϋ]l���ds�F��Oۦ�.G���W���<l��G�^���?�Bm��E�M-F��s_$���˪ݸ�H۵'�9T
                                                                          �Q�$��_~�����tg�0�/mI�ɲ�H�>���3�h� �ݞ@��'���_LO����:��zU �F*�T�}X�*>�Ֆ"�R�,0(=���&,~[��p��B�|Uzr���t_�=�u��ec>�\�p��#B���    ��-���3�J�]�W-C�(�M�����;��d�<��>�gE.ܸB<ky$�NV���2ld���]
                ��̽}N    ����_]�ծg.��pi��⡵��G�4�J�NjӬ>�V�>gn����vފՈ{N!е�}PBϒQ ��|
  @2p3�1�Odpn^�m����G
e��E��
      n��� ��]PS��,�܄6*C ����J��)��T�]&&�K��m�KҀ�sS܁p���bS%~W�aʎqB,������6��7(��.ٜ��AwGji��r8K����O����I�w{"R��ӵ1��!�+ri�    �s?_�f�9�,�����Mn;���e��X*Z�z�>,㮎�!����Q��m��#Az������\O�::�'��x������4��^?
#�a��0�bv�T�� I�m���_�m�ڶz�y���~2a�\�L[��s�w�P�l�p,�Pm��~�    �|����Gr��Q!��Z�`d�=Fr��D+��
            ���2gP��~A�
�ĉ�ǭΫ�K�f|&��          �|5t�9�
             �̍y���J�XJ���L~-���d��0pp�g%o���y��k�+Zb֐Gʻ�>��W%�+R��2��D�,o�N��wG�(�O>vl�Y�����Oj�I��Eo��j�Mx��g�V�"����k��R�����A_��~̉����Ɗ/吥G��� �S
                                                                   �

                                                                    H�!�N��<aXN�|��.i���B�N�:��d�CDhЅ!���;�����"���
                                   �D�,�D/�1�$Uj
��Β&�J
G
        ג�
9���QPo7���d��ęƯa8DΛ����y�Nj�c���U3�A]�z�nm�l1�@
��Q��\�=
���eT& BϲB,�x�������z�v��
�
��k���½U+7،�B�������IAQ�9
�|x1�_a[l��娔�k�n^`9�yT���˟=�7��+�@���*G�Y�_��r��_���(�R�9Z5h:�,��
                                                                  V���h��[�¸�w�fXcuxr9�X�k�'��;o$w$bV���V_����F�_.�K&5�Ju�B�����̃��)ɁJ�-t
             L'i�8B%��I�7S I��Q7�ޟ�֙����#m$䀚�����=o�4qv�pA���2��/;���
e-����;���<��-����J�9�(
     ?_7f������3(����W�i�O�CnGe����{�ԧ����    �0H����j0�J�
                                                            �7�}�z���K�TѢ��
                                                                           �+���Y�[������yo�7�ݶ8m�}
����1�T�*}��C 1۳����Öog��˫T7o�Ɔh�$�^�=����-/
                                            ri��?HqZ��e��Xp
�ʏ$�
    U
     L�˨���N�Pb����m"��g��M~���O?��NhQ�@�~7�
                                            H���
                                                ���    8'1�k5����柳���M��z�"iO�/��:�yj�LTTlH��Ɉ��q�K�Ӯ�; P�߂���z+�^���C1#+
            X����.�J��m~�e@����fFQ��"Z���.@D8�4��.ǥ�i�����F�e��O�7ͧ���.���j�O�I�M�8�c]�]��,�`�'@��N�5ް�S"�{�y5@��pJ�v-:&�a��S�(Pze]���4E36EDj��w�~&�
Pc���m�Gə�k�0�*�,&��V$
                      `)��G~�\���0���`
                                      ���
                                         <܎�p�2�-�9���<i3泟����?�X%����kʃ�P�@�]w�3������v�'D�#^�LXa�x6�$}��IH�&���ZB�{���H/��y��qT��z�&��
                                                         �taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$ file /etc/hosts
/etc/hosts: data
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$ ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2263 Apr 14 16:26 /etc/hosts
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$ ls -l /private/etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  2263 Apr 14 16:26 /private/etc/hosts
taylors-mbp:~ taylorscot$
```

I checked with coworkers who also have MBPs running Mojave, and all of their `/etc/hosts` files are standard text that be `cat`-ted or edited.

I very much appreciate any ideas or advice! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe restore it to its previous version from Time Machine.

Comment: Or copy it from one of your coworkers. I have no idea what happened to your /etc/hosts file, but whatever it was has rendered it useless garbage. It needs to be replaced with a good copy.

Comment: Both good ideas; I wound up going with copying in a replacement. There's some disk corruption that Disk Utility can't quite figure out, so I figure I need to bug IT. Thanks!